# Is this possible to connect to azure synapse analytics from aws ec2 (which is in vpc) instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, powerbi, amazon-vpc, azure-synapse

I have below existing architecture hosted in aws env

1. There is a FDMEE tool configured in ec2 which load data from HFM(outside aws) and dump in to the RDS-sql db, later this data is read in power BI in azure(through a gateway)- here we face some issue while refreshing the data set
2. Due to some business reason, connection from HFM to FDMEE should retain in AWS, however the data flow from FDMEE to RDS are subjected to change
3. So we are looking for a possibility to replace RDS-sql with azure synapse analytics, so that it become more efficient to refresh data in to power bi

so how can make a stable connection from FDMEE (which is in ec2- VPC) to azure synapse analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

For data on a private network you need to deploy a [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?context=%2Fazure%2Fsynapse-analytics%2Fcontext%2Fcontext&tabs=synapse-analytics) to load the data into Synapse, or push the data somewhere Synapse can access it directly, like S3 or Azure Storage.